# v-bind doesn't work with v-tabs I had to use v-model

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component, v-model

I'm using the component  of vuetify, and have set the default display as **page-2** (students) but when I click on second tab **professors** (page1) nothing happens.

when I changed **:value** with **v-model** it works.

I don't understand why it is working with **two way binding** and not the case with **one way binding**

AFAIK v-model works with input elements (form) and to get values in both direction: template/script & script/template, am I wrong ?

```
    <v-tabs :value="tab">
      <v-tab href="#page-2" >
        {{ 'students' }}
      </v-tab>
      <v-tab href="#page-1">
        {{ 'professors' }}
      </v-tab>
```

[actual display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqMKP.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to vuetify 3 documentation, you sould use `model-value` (see: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-tabs/#props-model-value)

update your code like this and it should works :

```
<v-tabs :model-value="tab">
  <v-tab href="#page-2" >
    {{ 'students' }}
  </v-tab>
  <v-tab href="#page-1">
    {{ 'professors' }}
  </v-tab>
</v-tabs>
```

Comment: thanks, but I already said that `v-model` solves the issue, I'm just wondering about the need of **two way binding** in this case instead of `:value` which represents the **one way binding**.


wheras according to my knowledge, the v-model is used to get inputs from users hence update from template to script,that's the point which I don't understand,  you see what I mean ?